# REST api call for listing Azure RBAC role definitions on "Resource" scope returns the defiitions on "ResourceGroup" scope. Why?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am making REST API call from my web app for listing the role definitions on the scope of "Azure Resource". But, the response has the role definitions on the "Resource Group scope".
What am I missing?

RequestURL: `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/################/resourceGroups/abc/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/abc/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions?api-version=2015-07-01&filter=atScopeAndBelow()`

The response contains 37 role definition which is at Resource group scope.

What am I missing in my REST api call that I am not able to get the roles on the specified scope only.

I am referring [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-manage-access-rest/).

Comment: That is the expected behaviour. This Rest API "lists all of the role that are available for assignment at the specified scope". If a Role is available to a parent resource, it's always available to the child resources. I think you misunderstand this API.

Comment: Are your trying to get the role definitions that are available for assignment only to a child resource, but not to its parent resource?

Comment: yes. you got my point. 
I don't want to filter the parent roles obtained. I want it to be done by the REST api call itself. 
It should return the filtered result as I am mentioning the Resource in my rest API call.

Comment: Well, Microsoft just does not provide that filter. For now, you can use 2 request. One is for the parent resource, and the other is for the child resource. Exclude the roles of the parent resource from the child resource's. By the way, you should not use the filter `atScopeAndBelow()`. For future use, you can go to the [AAD feedback site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory) to open a feature request for it.

Comment: at Parent scope(Resource group scope): **management.azure.com/subscriptions/##################/resourceGroups/abc/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions?api-version=2015-07-01**

Now this RG has a resource as Vnet with name "abc".

So, I call with this URL with child scope : **management.azure.com/subscriptions/##################/resourceGroups/abc/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/abc/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions?api-version=2015-07-01**

The response has same role definitions. 

If You check on portal, resources have different roles.