# How to get the role definitions by Azure management API which can only be assigned at "Resource" scope?

Tags: azure-management-api, azure-rbac

How to get the role definitions by Azure management API which can only be assigned at "**Resource**" scope?

When executing following query, all the role definitions are returned by the API:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<virtualMachineName>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions?api-version=2018-01-01-preview
```

The above return role definitions like `AcrPull` or `AcrImageSigner` which seems not be right role definitions for a virtual machine. In Azure portal, don't see these role definitions listed also.

[image]

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-definitions-list) Microsoft documentation, it seems that `$filter=atScopeAndBelow()` can be applied as OData filter, but it throws the bad request exception stating

> The filter 'atScopeAndBelow()' is not supported. Supported filters are either roleName eq '{value}' or type eq 'BuiltInRole|CustomRole'.

Any guidance to get only the role definitions which are validate at **Resource** scope level?

Note - there was [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397563/rest-api-call-for-listing-azure-rbac-role-definitions-on-resource-scope-return) asked 5 years back but it has no responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can give below command to list all the roles and their description.

```
Get-AzRoleDefinition | FT Name, Description
```

For assigning the role for resource scope you can directly do it from azure portal itself. This is the procedure that you can follow.

[image]

1. Select the resource that you want to assign.
2. Under  **Manage**, select  **Roles**  to see the list of roles for Azure resources.

[image]

3. Select a member or group you want to assign to the role and then click  **Select**.

[image]

For more information you can refer it from [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-resource-roles-assign-roles#role-assignment-conditions).

Comment: I'm looking a way find relevant role definitions through API not by portal. Can you point in that direction? The question here is that when fetched role definitions with resource scope, the management API returns all the built-in role even those are not shown on Azure portal for ex - `AcrPull` or `AcrImageSigner` which seems not be right role definitions for a virtual machine.

Comment: @SwethaKandikondaMT - any input?